# how to log the boot time for each controller and directive

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

I'm optimize my angular app. I found that only bootstrap the angular app will cost hundred milliseconds.

```
console.time("ng-boot");
angular.bootstrap("myapp"); 
console.time("ng-boot");
```

the time is nearly 300ms!!!

then I want to get all the running time of each controller(init) and directive(postLink maybe...), during the "bootstrap" phase. how can I achieve that?

of course I can get the time by adding logs in every controllers and link functions in directives. but I have too many directives. I want to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

personally i suggest you use chrome developer tools, profiles tab.
it has great tools to check speed, memory, cpu. much better than console.log everywhere.

Comment: yes, I know those tools. but it's difficult to locate the problem by using those tools. if angular provide some solution, it will be easier to find the inefficient code.

Comment: so look at "AngularJS Batarang" which is an extension to the chrome developer tools, specifically for angular. i don't use it much, but it might solve your issues.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have tried both the profiles in chrome developer tools and "AngularJS Batarang". finally I found the bottleneck.